# User logged in on website in browser: can I access from C#?

Tags: c#, .net

I wonder if the following is possible.

A user logs in on my website, using a username and password using his default browser.

Later on, my C# program is run on the same PC. I want to check if the user is logged in in the default browser, so I can access a webpage that is in the registered-only area. Is this somehow possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I number of possibilities come to mind:

- You could check their cookie folder for a valid cookie for your site
- Check the browser history (perhaps using a toolbar)
- Use the [web browser control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.webbrowser.aspx) so that users log-in through your app

I have never seen either of the above in practice.

I think the best method would be to set up the site to ask for credentials if they're not logged in - so the user can enter them and continue.  You'll find this method in most (if not all) of the major websites out there that have client installed software (such as the [Gmail Notifier](http://toolbar.google.com/gmail-helper/notifier_windows.html))

Answer (score 0):

You could possibly do it with a cookie saved on the machine, you would need to find where its stored and the naming of the cookie or some kind of api to read the cookie.

here is a few links
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.cookiecontainer.aspx

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.application.getcookie.aspx

http://bytes.com/topic/c-sharp/answers/677862-reading-creating-cookies-local-machine-using-windows-application

http://www.codeproject.com/Messages/2981086/How-to-read-cookies-in-winforms-Net.aspx